# Flutter row element remain center even using alignment or column element could not change it row align left?

Tags: flutter, alignment, containers

I have the following container and in it I call a function to create child widget. The issue it that child row always remain as center align. I have tried two methods

1. alignment:Alignment.topLeft,
2. I have tried to embed it further into a column and tried crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start.

Both methods fails to align the element to the left. It keep remains into the center part of the container. What could be wrong below is my codes.

```
Container(
  alignment:Alignment.topRight,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          buildDateTime("datetime"),
        ]
      )
    ],
  )
),
```

Below is the widget which I call to build the row.

```
Widget buildDateTime(String plate) {
  return new Container(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.access_time, size: 15.0, color: lightGrey),
          Text(
            ' 23/01/20202',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: lightGrey,
              fontFamily: "Bpreplay",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 14.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            ' 09:00',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: lightGrey,
              fontFamily: "Bpreplay",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 14.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the crossAxisAligment property of the `Row` Widget?

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes I have tried that too but still the same.Weird I tried all options but it just does not seems to move at all.

Comment: @newbie Share screen shot pls if possible

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat I have added the screen shot as per your request?

Comment: @newbie was my answer what you were trying to achieve? If so, remember to mark the answer as correct so that other users can see it in the future.

Comment: @JoãoSoares no I tried it didnt work as per my problem ? If you see my screen shot everything is in the center right. I want all to move to left

Comment: @newbie I've updated my code with the `Row` property `mainAxisAligment` swapped from `spaceBetween` to `start`. That should do what you want.

Comment: @JoãoSoares is the same I tried all these combinations before too.

Comment: @newbie I've added a screenshot of what my code does. If you are getting a different result then you have other things, outside the code you showed us, affecting the positioning. Please keep in mind that I removed the extra Columns that you had. You should copy all of my code, not just specific lines to get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

I've made the Clock icon align to the left, Date centered and time aligned to the right. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
Container(
  color: Colors.grey,
  alignment:Alignment.topRight,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
  child: buildDateTime("datetime")
);

Widget buildDateTime(String plate) {
  return new Container(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.access_time, size: 15.0, color: Colors.grey[100]),
          Text(
            ' 23/01/20202',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey[100],
              fontFamily: "Bpreplay",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 14.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            ' 09:00',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey[100],
              fontFamily: "Bpreplay",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 14.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

My result:

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: nope still the same I suspect some other above container or row or column is the one giving problem?

Comment: @newbie Like I said on my comment above. Did you copy all of my code? Is what you see on my screenshot what you want to achieve?

Comment: There has to be something wrong in your surrounding code. What I showed on the screenshot is exactly what my code does. There's nothing else in the app. Try loading this code in a view with nothing else and see how it looks.

Comment: @Joaa yes I suspect something on the up which is causing the issue. Let me debug it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce the issue you mentioned. For me, its occupies full width.

Try this,

```
Widget buildDateTime(String plate) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.access_time, size: 15.0, color: Colors.grey),
        Text(
          ' 23/01/20202',
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontFamily: "Bpreplay",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 14.0,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          ' 09:00',
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontFamily: "Bpreplay",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 14.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: is it could be the parent column or row which need to cross alignment settings too ?

Comment: yes. its probably problem from outside which holds the `Container`

Comment: yes its actually embeded via few other container,column,row so I think I will need to check all of it. Should I add all the parent element cross alignment feature?

Comment: Not sure. But you can try that.

Comment: What is the end goal. just displaying the list of dates?

Comment: @newbie I updated the answer. I think it will force you to align left i guess.

Comment: @What impact will this do mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,?

Comment: alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, this does not help either

Comment: Is there any row in parent? if yes set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` and `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`

Comment: Yes there is column,row,column,column as in sequence as the parents

Comment: Shouldnt I be putting crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, cause thats what I saw in google ?

Comment: in `Row` horizontal is mainaxis

Comment: @What do you mean in row horizontal is mainaxis

Comment: In `Row` children are arranged in horizontal manner. so horizontal is the mainAxis in row. Likewise in `Column` children are arranged in vertical manner. so vertical is mainAxis for column. Refer [this](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041)

Comment: yes I have been referring to this link all the while at times I get confuse too.I  get confused and mix up with crossAxisAlignment I notice if you have column then this settings place a bigger role?

Comment: If the parent widget (either row or column) wants to be small and center aligned then then the children cannot do nothing, unless you hardcode size somewhere in the widget tree.

Comment: opps so no other solution is it. So meaning that the parent must left algin too. When you say hardcode meaning how you do that?